# Setting up TOR Access Point [TOR doesn't work]

Tags: networking, wifi

I have used this guide: 
https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/

to set up a standard access point for clients to connect to. The static IP address I have used is: 192.168.200.1/24 and made sure the same IP addresses / network is defined in other config files that the guide asks me to edit. Everything works fine.

Then I have used this guide to set up tor: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-tor-access-point/

I have made sure I use the same IP in the torrc config file as above and it does not work.

I have checked the status of tor service and this is what I get:

```
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Sun 2018-04-01 20:00:44 UTC; 3s ago
Process: 1106 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1106 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service

Apr 01 20:00:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Apr 01 20:00:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

Where it says "active (exited)", I'm pretty sure it should be "active(running)".

I have also checked the log file and this is what I get:

```
Apr 01 19:59:16.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.9.14 (git-a211f886ad759cab) opening log file.
Apr 01 19:59:16.006 [notice] Tor 0.2.9.14 (git-a211f886ad759cab) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.0f and Zlib 1.2.8.
Apr 01 19:59:16.007 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 01 19:59:16.007 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Apr 01 19:59:16.007 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 01 19:59:16.018 [warn] The TransListenAddress option is deprecated, and will most likely be removed in a future version of Tor. Use TransPort instead. (If you think this is a mistake, please let us know!)
Apr 01 19:59:16.018 [warn] The DNSListenAddress option is deprecated, and will most likely be removed in a future version of Tor. Use DNSPort instead. (If you think this is a mistake, please let us know!)
Apr 01 19:59:16.018 [notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.200.10:53' for DNSPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
Apr 01 19:59:16.018 [notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.200.10:9040' for TransPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
Apr 01 19:59:16.021 [notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.200.10:53' for DNSPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
Apr 01 19:59:16.021 [notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.200.10:9040' for TransPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
Apr 01 19:59:16.021 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 01 19:59:16.021 [notice] Opening DNS listener on 192.168.200.10:53
Apr 01 19:59:16.021 [notice] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 192.168.200.10:9040
Apr 01 19:59:16.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Apr 01 19:59:16.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Apr 01 19:59:18.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Apr 01 19:59:19.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Apr 01 19:59:19.000 [notice] Signaled readiness to systemd
Apr 01 19:59:19.000 [notice] Opening Socks listener on /var/run/tor/socks
Apr 01 19:59:19.000 [notice] Opening Control listener on /var/run/tor/control
Apr 01 19:59:26.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Apr 01 19:59:26.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Apr 01 19:59:27.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Apr 01 19:59:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
Apr 01 20:00:44.000 [notice] Interrupt: exiting cleanly.
```

Also I have noticed the warn logs and I have decided to delete the "TransListenAddress" and "DNSListenAddress" from the config file and it did not make a difference.

I have tried different tutorials that use different techniques to set up the access point, including the ones that use the RPI-Wireless-Hotspot git hub. And it still doesn't work. I'm starting to think that there is a problem with TOR or the newest Raspbian.

**UPDATE:** I managed to make it work using an older version of Raspbian, however it still does not work on the newest version, therefore it still needs a fix.

Comment: Welcome! May I recommend: "Secure your network with TOR", The MagPi Magazine, issue 67, page 68, https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/67/ (PDF download is free)

Comment: Doesn't work either. Nothing works. Has to be a problem with TOR or Raspbian Stretch.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with TOR and/or Stretch, but what do you mean exactly?

Comment: No tutorial I have found on the internet works, and most use different ways to set up an access point and tor. Therefore it has to be a problem with TOR or Raspbian Stretch as I was able to set up an access point using one method, however I couldn't set up TOR.

Comment: "I managed to make it work using an older version" Glad to hear, but please add version number to make your input more helpful for others in future, thanks!